# Permutations by sub groups in python

Tags: python, permutation

I have a list of dataframe columns, L.

```
L=[AA ,  AS  ,  AD  , BB  , BC  , C ,  D ]
```

and I need all combinations of items, in no particular order. So I can use permutations I think?

However I can only have one A and one B in each combination;

So I need a combination of

```
A=[AA,AS,AD]
B=[BB,BC]
All others=[C,D]
```

I also don't need all to be items to be present in the outputted permutations. 
A few example combinations below:

```
AA,BB,C,D
AA,BB,C
AA
AA,BB
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I also don't need all to be items to be present. So a few example combinations below"?

Comment: So if I havel, 3 items in the list, A, B and C. the results would be. [A], [B], [A,B],[A,C],[C,B],[C],[A,B,C]

Comment: Where does the D comes from in the example in your comment?

Comment: yep that was a error, I've updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). You can get it with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Since you don't need every element, you could append `None` to each list and remove them afterwards.

Here's an example:

```
from itertools import product
for choices in product(['AA','AS','AD',None],['BB', 'BC', None], ['C', None], ['D', None]):
    print(' '.join(column for column in choices if column))
```

It outputs:

```
AA BB C D
AA BB C
AA BB D
AA BB
AA BC C D
AA BC C
AA BC D
AA BC
AA C D
AA C
AA D
AA
AS BB C D
AS BB C
AS BB D
AS BB
AS BC C D
AS BC C
AS BC D
AS BC
AS C D
AS C
AS D
AS
AD BB C D
AD BB C
AD BB D
AD BB
AD BC C D
AD BC C
AD BC D
AD BC
AD C D
AD C
AD D
AD
BB C D
BB C
BB D
BB
BC C D
BC C
BC D
BC
C D
C
D
```